# resourceGroupField in full calendar not working in angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar

I have implement full calendar scheduler in angular 4.i am refer this link https://fullcalendar.io/.
Full calendar need to implement grouping of resources but its not working for me.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "demo6",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.2",
    "angular-draggable": "^1.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.9.0",
    "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^1.9.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.16.0"
  }
}
```

And here code i have tried.

`let containerEl: JQuery = $('#calendar');

```
        containerEl.fullCalendar({
            schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            aspectRatio: 1.2,
            scrollTime: '06:00',
            header: {
                left: 'today prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'timelineDay,agendaWeek,month'
            },
            defaultView: 'timelineDay',
            resourceGroupField: 'jobnum',
            resourceLabelText: 'Jobs',                              
            resources: [
                {}
            ],
            events: [

            ],
            drop: function (date) {
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            },
            eventReceive: function (event) {
                console.log('eventReceive', event);
                self.getEvent();
            },
            eventDrop: function (event) {
                console.log('eventDrop', event);
            }
        });`
```

When i have use `jobnum` as property name for grouping resources is give me error

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(39,29): error TS2345: Types of
>   property 'resources' are incompatible. Type '{ jobnum: string; }[]' is
>   not assignable to type 'ResourceSourceInput'. Type '{ jobnum: string;
>   }[]' is not assignable to type 'ResourceFunction'. Type '{ jobnum:
>   string; }[]' provides no match for the signature '(callback:
>   ResourceFunctionCallback, start: Moment, end: Moment, timezone:
>   string): void'.

anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the error message you're getting

Comment: Can you please create working copy at https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: I am getting this error
 `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(39,29): error TS2345: 
  Types of property 'resources' are incompatible.
    Type '{ jobnum: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ResourceSourceInput'.
      Type '{ jobnum: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'ResourceFunction'.
        Type '{ jobnum: string; }[]' provides no match for the signature '(callback: ResourceFunctionCallback, start: Moment, end: Moment, timezone: string): void'.`

Answer (score 1):

You need change your initialization like below code. You need to use `<any>`

```
(<any>$('#calendar')).fullCalendar({
...
...
});
```